# make my enumerated index correspond if I manually peek forward in the generator?

Tags: python

```
>>> gen = iter(['a','b','c','d'])
>>> for i, line in enumerate(gen):
...     print str(i) + ', ' + line
...     if (i == 1):
...         print 'saw 1'
...         print 'next: ' + gen.next()
...
0, a
1, b
saw 1
next: c
2, d
```

As you can see I'd prefer to see `3, d` as the understanding (an invariant I'd like to preserve, if you will: because what other reason would `enumerate` serve?) is that `i` corresponds to the index of `line`. the `next()` takes a dump on that.

Sadly this attempt fails as `i` gets set to what the for loop thinks it should be:

```
>>> gen = iter(['a','b','c','d'])
>>> for i, line in enumerate(gen):
...     print str(i) + ', ' + line
...     if (i == 1):
...         print 'saw 1'
...         print 'next: ' + gen.next()
...         i = i + 1
...
0, a
1, b
saw 1
next: c
2, d
```

Whats the answer? Ditch `enumerate` to manually track the index? I was hoping there's some high-level programming that can accomodate this sort of control flow.

I'm parsing a file and occasionally need to read the contents of the next line if it exists (hence calling `next()` on generator) but i then have to deal with the loop control flow as a result.

Because I already know how to do it, an answer that does this by first reading out and fully evaluating the generator will not be accepted (but feel free to post such an answer, i'll upvote it).

Comment: What about `if (i==2): continue` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `enumerate` iterator all the way through.

```
>>> gen = enumerate(['a','b','c','d'])
>>> for i, line in gen:
...     print str(i) + ', ' + line
...     if (i == 1):
...         print 'saw 1'
...         print 'next: ' + gen.next()[1]
...
0, a
1, b
saw 1
next: c
3, d
```

Note the index to access the second element of the tuple when printing `next`. You can also ditch the explicit call to `iter` this way. If you want the explicit call to `iter` in case the behavior of `enumerate` changes, you should put it on the outside (since the whole point would be to be sure you're dealing with an iterator):

```
>>> gen = iter(enumerate(['a','b','c','d']))
```

Comment: Lol, I had posted this, then I realised the page didn't update. +1

Comment: @Haidro Sorry to steal your thunder. Thanks for being a good sport. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
gen = iter(['a','b','c','d'])
i = 0
for line in gen:
    print str(i) + ', ' + line
    i += 1
    if (i == 1):
        print 'saw 1'
        print 'next: ' + gen.next()
        i += 1
```

If you can convert the iterator to a list the logic can be made simpler, as you can iterate over indexes from 0 to len-1 and just increment the index, rather than needing to keep track of the generator's place and what index that would correspond to (which could lead to mismatch bugs).